# Android ImageView setImageResource doesn't update Image

Tags: java, android, imageview

In my application, the user must upload a few attachments in order to complete registration. 
I display a check-list of attachments. When the user clicks on an item, I launch an intent to pick a file from the device. In `onActivityResult`, I call `setFileImage()`on the current fragment to update the checkbox drawable.

The problem is that calling `imageView.setImageResource` doesn't work. I tried replacing the ImageViews with backgroudn and then using `imageView.setBackgroundResource` but that doesn't work either.

I'm completely at a loss and I could really use some help to debug this code:

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Attachment attachment = pathFromActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(attachment == null){
            return;
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(attachment.getPath()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(attachment.getMimeType())) {
            switch (mCurrentFile) {
                case RegisterStage5Fragment.COMMERCIAL_REGISTRATION_IMAGE:
                    mRegistration.setCommercial_registration_copy(attachment);
                    break;

                case RegisterStage5Fragment.OWNER_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE:
                    mRegistration.setOwner_national_card_copy(attachment);
                    break;

                case RegisterStage5Fragment.ACCREDITATION_IMAGE:
                    mRegistration.setAccreditation_file_copy(attachment);
                    break;

                case RegisterStage5Fragment.CONTACT_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE:
                    mRegistration.setContact_national_card_copy(attachment);
                    break;

                case RegisterStage5Fragment.BANK_INFORMATION_PROOF_IMAGE:
                    mRegistration.setBank_information_proof_copy(attachment);
                    break;
            }
            mRegisterStage5Fragment.setFileImage(mCurrentFile);
        }
        mCurrentFile = -1;
    }
}
```

**RegisterStage5Fragment.java**

```
public class RegisterStage5Fragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static final int COMMERCIAL_REGISTRATION_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int OWNER_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE = 2;
    public static final int ACCREDITATION_IMAGE = 3;
    public static final int CONTACT_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE = 4;
    public static final int BANK_INFORMATION_PROOF_IMAGE = 5;

    @InjectView(R.id.commercialRegistrationImage) View mCommercialRegistrationImage;
    @InjectView(R.id.ownerNationalCardImage) View mOwnerNationalCardImage;
    @InjectView(R.id.accreditationImage) View mAccreditationImage;
    @InjectView(R.id.contactNationalCardImage) View mContactNationalCardImage;
    @InjectView(R.id.bankInformationProofImage) View mBankInformationProofImage;


    RegisterActivity mRegisterActivity;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_stage_5, null, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, contentView);
        mRegisterActivity = (RegisterActivity) getActivity();
        ((RegisterActivity) getActivity()).setRegisterStage5Fragment(this);

        return contentView;
    }

    public void setFileImage(int fileImage) {

        switch (fileImage) {
            case RegisterStage5Fragment.COMMERCIAL_REGISTRATION_IMAGE:
               mCommercialRegistrationImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
                break;

            case RegisterStage5Fragment.OWNER_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE:
                mOwnerNationalCardImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
                break;

            case RegisterStage5Fragment.ACCREDITATION_IMAGE:
                mAccreditationImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
                break;

            case RegisterStage5Fragment.CONTACT_NATIONAL_CARD_IMAGE:
                mContactNationalCardImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
                break;

            case RegisterStage5Fragment.BANK_INFORMATION_PROOF_IMAGE:
                mBankInformationProofImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
                //mBankInformationProofImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, _it does not work_? Do you run into any errors? If so, could you post the traceback?

Comment: When the user adds the attachment, I call setImageResource to change the drawable but the imageView doesn't update the image. I checked logcat but there is no relevant output.

Comment: Have you verified (using either the debugger or logging statements) that the parameter passed to the setFileImage method (i.e. mCurrentFile) has the value that you expect, and that the branch of the 'case' statement that you expect to be executed is? I'm guessing that you wind up passing the default value (-1) to setFileImage for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I did check that. mCurrentFile has a valid value.